# What is the best way to get a dump of a single process in Windows Server 2003?

Tags: windows-server-2003, process, dump

I've got a process in Windows Server 2003 that I want to get a dump of, as it is taking up way more RAM than it should. It's been suggested that I use procdump, userdump, or install windbg. I would like to know what would be best to get a dmp file of that process. Do I have to crash Windows to get a dump? It sounds like I might have to, but I would rather not.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: With procdump you do not have to crash the kernel.  See this page: http://support.citrix.com/article/ctx124508 and the pages at the bottom for more useful infos.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you [ProcDump](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/dd996900) because it can start the dump in certain situations automatically that you program.